# Changing the default TestRunner in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, default

All tests should be run with jUnit3, if i run a non-configured Test, it tries to use the default-TestRunner (jUnit4).

So, i have to go into the run/debug configuration, change the TestRunner to "jUnit3" and run it again.

On EVERY Test. This just disturbs the workflow.

So, is there an option to REMOVE jUnit4 as possible TestRunner, or even better, change the Default TestRunner to jUnit3 ?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the junit 3 JAR is on the classpath and not the JUnit 4 JAR. Then, Eclipse should do the right thing.

Comment: I tried this before, i then just throws a NoClassDefFoundException ;), default TestRunner stays jUnit4 :/

Comment: Please post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: Also check your error log. This behavior of Eclipse isn't right. For me, I get the correct runner.